# My $.getJSON() script isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, instagram

I'm just starting with this JSON / AJAX thing and I'm having a hard time figuring out why this is not working... 
I've searched in lots of places but no detailed description on how to use $.getJSON is provided. Can you please help me out? And Can you provide some info why my script wasn't working?! I suppose it's because of the `i, item` and `data.response[i]` but I can't find what they are needed for..

```
var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?access_token=18360510.5b9e1e6.de870cc4d5344ffeaae178542029e98b";

$.getJSON(url, function(data) 
{
    $.each(data.response, function (i, item) 
    {
        instagram += '<li>';
        instagram += '<a href="'+ data.response[i].link +'" target="_blank">';
        instagram += '<div class="imag3" style="background-image: url('+ data.response[i].images.low_resolution.url +');">';
        instagram += '</div></a>';
        instagram += '</li>';

        $('#instagram-cont').html(instagram);
    });
```

## Update

as suggested I've used `console.log(data)`
and in the console it gave me a `Object` dropdown with inside `data: Array[15]`
so I updated my code like this:

```
var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?access_token=18360510.5b9e1e6.de870cc4d5344ffeaae178542029e98b";

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data.data, function (i, item) {
    instagram += '<li>';
    instagram += '<a href="'+ data.data[i].link +'" target="_blank">';
    instagram += '<div class="imag3" style="background-image: url('+ data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +');">';
    instagram += '</div></a>';
    instagram += '</li>';

    $('#instagram-cont').html(instagram);
    });
```

and it worked!!!
thanks everybody for the help

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Look at your JavaScript error console. What does it say?

Comment: Looks liek you have a syntax error.

Comment: Have you looked at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/? Imo, it is fairly detailed.

Comment: the error I get in the console is; `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` from the jQuery.js file on line 2 (it's minified)

Comment: @confuse: yes but they don't explain what `$.each(data.response, function (i, item) {` nor what I have to put if `data.response` or `item.response` and also they don't explain what the [i] stands for.

Comment: Is it a cross site scripting issue?  Might need to enable CORS.

Comment: Did you `console.log(data)` in your callback to see if you are getting *anything* back? Did you look at your browser console (network tab) to see what the response code is? Also, be sure to look at http://instagram.com/developer/

Comment: @user3933986 The documentation for `$.json()` doesn't explain those things because they have nothing to do with `$.json()`.

Comment: @user3933986 Please take that edit and make it into an answer...

Answer (score 1):

You may need to be using JSONP instead of a regular AJAX call.

http://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/76bew4vk/

`console.log` is your friend. Use it to see the structure of the data returned. I also changed the call to jsonp.

```
    var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?access_token=18360510.5b9e1e6.de870cc4d5344ffeaae178542029e98b";

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp'
})
.done(function(data){
    //console.log(data);
    $.each(data.data, function (i, item) 
    {
        instagram = '<li>';
        instagram += '<a href="'+ item.link +'" target="_blank">';
        instagram += '<div class="imag3" style="background-image: url('+item.images.low_resolution.url +');">';
        instagram += '</div></a>';
        instagram += '</li>';

        $('#instagram-cont').append(instagram);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use the "item" in the 'each' function instead of data.response[i]
Second, i think you wanna use changing the html outside of the each loop

Answer (score 0):

The returning JSON data stream does not contain a property "`data.response`"

Referring to this as a parameter `$.each(data.response, ....`will lead to the length error in `data.response[i].link`

Have a look at the structure of the returned JSON data and handle exceptions properly.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in the comments, I've used `console.log(data)`
and in the console it gave me an `Object` dropdown with inside `data: Array[15]`
so I updated my code like this:

```
var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?access_token=18360510.5b9e1e6.de870cc4d5344ffeaae178542029e98b";

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data.data, function (i, item) {
    instagram += '<li>';
    instagram += '<a href="'+ data.data[i].link +'" target="_blank">';
    instagram += '<div class="imag3" style="background-image: url('+ data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +');">';
    instagram += '</div></a>';
    instagram += '</li>';

    $('#instagram-cont').html(instagram);
    });
```

and it worked!!!
thanks everybody for the help